# Amazing time picker is not returning AM and PM with time

Tags: angular, timepicker

here is my method of call it in my component

```
 open() {
const amazingTimePicker = this.atp.open({
  theme: 'material-orange',
  time:this.Start
});
amazingTimePicker.afterClose().subscribe(time => {
    this.Start = time;
    this.onchange()
});
}
```

here my html file tag where im using it

```
  <input disabled   theme="material-orange" type="time" matInput class="material" atp-time-picker value="{{Start}}"/>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `atp-time-picker` directive, and open the dialog programmatically. Also make sure your input type is text, not time. then try:

```
open() {
  const amazingTimePicker = this.atp.open({
    theme: 'material-orange',
    time:this.Start
  });
  amazingTimePicker.afterClose().subscribe(time => {
    this.Start = time + ( time > 12 ? 'am' : 'pm'); // enhance logic
  });
}
```

and for template:

```
<input type="text" (click)="open()" value="20:55" value="{{Start}}" />
```